# How to delete XML node by text() on Oracle 11g using XQUERY?

Tags: xml, oracle, text, oracle11g, xquery

My question is how to delete a XML node by using the function text() on Oracle11g using Xquery. 
Here is my XML column (USERS) structure:

```
<users>
 <user>user1</user>
 <user>user2</user>
</users>
```

I have done it by using DELETEXML in the following manner:

```
UPDATE GROUPS SET USERS =
DELETEXML(USERS,'/users/user[text()="user1"]') 
WHERE ID = 'clients';
```

But according to official documentation DELETEXML will be deprecated in future releases, so I am trying to translate this query to XMLQUERY. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/app_depr_upd.htm#ADXDB6044

```
UPDATE GROUPS SET USERS =
XMLQuery('copy $tmp := . modify delete node
        $tmp/users/user[text()="user1"] return $tmp'
       PASSING USERS RETURNING CONTENT)
WHERE ID = 'clients';
```

I get the following error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation: XQuery Update connot be compiled
19112. 00000 -  "error raised during evaluation: %s"
*Cause:    The error function was called during evaluation of the XQuery expression.
*Action:   Check the detailed error message for the possible causes.
```

I have researched but have not found a solution to this problem. I can delete the node by its attributes [@attribute = "something"] or by its position [1] but not by text.

Any help is apprecciated! Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why this should be invalid XQuery code, and evaluation with other XQuery engines returns the result you expect. You might want to consider opening a bugreport  Anyway, which exact version of Oracle 11g are you using? Oracle 11g did not have support for XQuery Update from the beginning.

Comment: I'm using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

In 11.2.0.4 your code works.
Xquery(version 1.0) has two comparison operator `eq` and `=`. In most cases its works in the same way. But there is slight difference.

- `eq` - is designed to compare "single values "
- `=` - is general comparison to compare sequences/sets

11.2.0.4 probably has newer version of xquery implementation (version 1.0-ml) where this restriction was relaxed.

This is proper way.

```
UPDATE GROUPS SET USERS =
XMLQuery('copy $tmp := . modify delete node
        $tmp/users/user[text() eq "user1"] return $tmp'
       PASSING USERS RETURNING CONTENT);
```

And this should also work

```
UPDATE GROUPS SET USERS =
XMLQuery('copy $tmp := . modify delete node
        $tmp/users/user[./text()="user1"] return $tmp'
       PASSING USERS RETURNING CONTENT);
```

Comment: Hello Arkadiusz, thank you for your response. Unfortunately I have tried both your methods and keep getting the same error.